# Typescript Omit seems to transform an union into an intersection

Tags: javascript, typescript, union-types, intersection-types

I have this type

```
type Cartesian = { kind: 'cartesian'; x: number; y: number; }
type Polar = { kind: 'polar'; angle: number; distance: number }
type Movement = { name: string } & (Cartesian | Polar);
```

that I can use like this

```
const move = (movement: Movement) => { /* whatever */ };
move({ name: 'top right', kind: 'cartesian', x: 10, y: 10 });
move({ name: 'left', kind: 'polar', angle: Math.PI, distance: 10 });
```

but for some reason, I can't use it like this

```
const unnamedMove = (unnamedMovement: Omit<Movement, 'name'>) => {
    move({ name: 'default', ...unnamedMovement })
}
```

because TS throws a 2345:

```
Argument of type '{ kind: "cartesian" | "polar"; name: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Movement'.
  Type '{ kind: "cartesian" | "polar"; name: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ name: string; } & Polar'.
    Type '{ kind: "cartesian" | "polar"; name: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Polar': angle, distance
```

I don't understand this.

If I am not mistaken `Omit<Movement, 'name'>` should be equivalent to the union type `Cartesian | Polar`, which would make `{ name: 'default', ...unnamedMovement }` a `Movement`, and all things should work.

However, it looks like TS infers `Omit<Movement, 'name'>` as if it was the union type `Cartesian & Polar`, thus the error.

Is it a bug or a mistake from my part?

[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwghgJ2BAzgSzgOygXigbygGs1MATALigHIBjRZdLagbigA8rMBXAWwCMICNiC59BwqAF8AUKEhQACgHsANolwFipSjTBrErKFgDmqiGIFC2ZNCmBZaFqDysJpc8NACyygG4QvBCYwJqEmHBBVPYIpCbSUABkUAAU8EioGNgAPkoGCACULDIytMqY9lC8-tB4KdUBQSFUvo3BwAW4AHxaAPQAVFAA7gAWcMgB7v290sUNECnhkc7UwMpgULEmI8DUADTa5FR0DJnMB5xQAIwADAei1zfSRTLziy7Lx+YAZrsHJEc9Pl9sZMGZnN5xiMAHSKACSB1s9kczluz2KpXKlW4mAiQTIrVqqRxeIgBJqTWAVAA8rw0MAADyEykHaik6hdTo4Hr4GRQflVGrvUnHMgQb5wbiqP5QaFyknLcltELPGRSIA)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably want [Distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types). From the docs

`When conditional types act on a generic type, they become distributive when given a union type.`

This means that you can declare something like this

```
type DOmit<T, K extends string> = T extends unknown
  ? Omit<T, K>
  : never;
```

and then use it like this

```
const unnamedMove = (unnamedMovement: DOmit<Movement, "name">) => {
    move({ name: 'default', ...unnamedMovement })
}
```

[Playground here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwghgJ2BAzgSzgOygXigbygGs1MATALigHIBjRZdLagbigA8rMBXAWwCMICNiC59BwqAF8AUKEhQACgHsANolwFipSjTBrErKFgDmqiGIFC2ZNCmBZaFqDysJpc8NACyygG4QvBCYwJqEmHBBVPYIpCbSUABkUAAU8EioGNgAPkoGCACULDIytMqY9lC8-tB4KdUBQSFUvo3BwAW4AHxaAPQAVFAA7gAWcMgB7v290sUNECnhkc7UwMpgULEmI8DUADTa5FR0DJnMB5xQAIwADAei1zfSRTLziy7Lx+YAZrsHJEc9Pl9sZMGZnN5xiMAHSKACSB1s9kczluz2KngUABEAPK8NDAAA8ABUDgBpKAQdjIcgoKAxOI9PDEynU4JkOlYEAyKBQAD8UDxBJJ5K6PKgXAgkwxZQqoW4mAiQTIrVqqQVSogKpqTWAVFx+KJqt1BwARJrTV1Ojgevhxby3ksojQyBBvnBuKo-lBob6NcttW0Qs8ZFIgA)